# two of table view cell has same memory reference

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I have a table view and in this table view I have 11 cells. In these cells I see same value. When I check on debug view hierarchy these cells, they have same memory reference. [image: xcode log screen]

I crashed these bug twice today, why could it be? Thanks for the help!

Comment: it because of  of dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier is to use less memory. If the screen can fit 4 or 5 table cells, then with reuse you only need to have 4 or 5 table cells allocated in memory even if the table has 1000 entries.

Comment: Are you sure that it's not a dequeue of cell?

Comment: how can I fix it? @KKRocks

Comment: this is not a problem . can you add error log .